# Sort on a specific column

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I am using this code:

```
Sub CopyUniqueCityList()

Dim rCityList As Range

With Sheets("MasterSheet")
    With .Range(.Range("F1"), .Range("F1").End(xlDown))
        .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
        Set rCityList = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    .ShowAllData
End With

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets

    If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible And ws.Name <> "MasterSheet" Then

        rCityList.Copy ws.Range("F1")

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

to get a unique list copied to different sheets. This all works fine. (Thanks Scott...:-))

Anyway, now I am trying to sort on this unique list.

I'm trying to do the sort in the for, but should I be trying in the With?

In any case, I continue to get errors. I started with recording a macro and got to here:

```
ws.Range("F1:F").Sort key1:=Columns(6), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

but the sort continues to elude me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, "F1:F" is not a valid range. Either use "F:F" for the whole column, or "F1:F100" for a portion of the column.

Also, where you have ws.Range("F:F")..., you actually want the entire table you are sorting, not just the column that you are sorting on. So, for instance, if you have a column to the right that you want sorted by column F, use the same code, but start with ws.Range("F:G")...

If you put this in the "With" block, it will be done on only Master Sheet. I'm guessing you want it in the For Loop, which will be done once for each sheet except MasterSheet

Comment: You are correct, I don't really want it done on the mastersheet.  I used your suggestion and still recieve an error: The sort reference is not valid. Make sure it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort by box isn't the same of blank.

Comment: Ok, it was both of you that helped solve the problem. I added the following to the for...and tada...it worked.    ws.Range("F:H").Sort key1:=ws.Columns("F"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes                      Not sure how to give you both credit??Thanks a bunch guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing key1:=Columns(6) with key1:=ws.Columns("F1").

Shouldn't really make a difference here, but assuming that your data in Column F doesn't have anything else underneath it, you can use VBA to find the last row in column F with data. Looks like --> ws.Range("F1:F" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).